# how to force asp.net page not to use any stored resources in client side computer?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have done some updates in company's website, but the problem I tried many testing computers which I used them to test & view the website before, and they give me some old images which already have been updated in company's website. I am forced now to press (Ctrl + F5) to reload the page and get the new version of images and content, so is there a way or methodology in asp.net to prevent using old resources of the website from client computer and always asking for resources from server?

thanks,...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you went into a classic case of caching problem.

One way is to use following meta tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML output:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

The value for the attribute should be equals or less 0. This tag commands the browser to reload all ressources from original server and ignoring all caches.

Btw. The zero value says in how many seconds the content will be expire. You also got the option to define it to particular date. If you want to go this way  you have to define the date into international format like this:

```
content="Sat, 15 Dec 2001 12:00:00 GMT"
```

Hopefully it will help.

PS: Take an eye of the comment from ManselUK. Stackoverflow.com is a community that is base of **give and take** and not only take.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty trick is to use a fake query string, i.e.:

`http://myPage.com/page.aspx?code=123456`

And make the code part random each time.